# Docker compose gives error container name already taken

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The use case for me is that I need to use the containers of 3rd party services like Mongodb and InfluxDb as a part of my complete docker service setup. The containers from these 3rd party services may or may not exists in my machine. I want to use the same container and prevent docker compose from recreating them if they already exists and recreate them if they don't exist.

I have created a docker compose file as below:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongo-database:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:${Mongo_Service_Version}
    restart: always
    ports: 
     - "30041:27017"
    networks: 
     - internal-network
    volumes: 
     - data:/data/db
  service-test:
    container_name: service-test
    image:service1:v1
    restart: always
    ports: 
     - "30091:80"
    networks: 
     - internal-network
    depends_on: 
     - mongo-database
```

I have created a mongo service and then created an application service-test that depends on the mongo service.
(Note : Service-test is just for demonstration purpose)

The problem I face is that when I run the docker-compose command to up the service I am able to do it successfully. The docker compose first creates a mongo container and then a service container but the problem is that if a mongo container with the same name and same configuration already exists the docker compose gives the error that the container with same name already exists.
My use case is that i don't want to remove the old container manually and recreate it using docker-compose. My expectation is that docker compose is smart enough to handle this situation. Docker compose should not try to recreate the container if it already exists.

If there is just the service version upgrade and we run the docker compose command , docker compose behave smart and does not recreates the mongo container but why it does not acts smart when the mongo container is created separately/manually.

Comment: It's not about Docker Compose is smart enough or not. If you were they, you will do the same. Incase you're running a mongo-abc container manually for your production and docker-compose just remove it and create a new one, who will take the responsible for that? With your case, I think you could just let docker-compose create service name by itself, or use another name which not conflict with any existing containers.

Comment: To add to what Toan Quoc Ho said. If "the container" already exists it's very likely part of another setup. You've either created it manually or have another docker-compose project that also uses mongoDB. Obviously you'd want the first container/database keep running with that other project ... docker-compose is actually smart enough to reuse containers it created for that particular project associated with that particular docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @NikolayManolov you are absolutely right with the scenario. I have a separate docker-compose file that has created a mongo container and i want the new docker compose file to reuse this mongo container. I feel this could be a valid scenario.(not sure what is Inherently  wrong in this scenario). Let's assume docker compose does not cater this scenario but still I need to understand how docker-compose reuses or creates a new container if does not exists  for a particular docker compose file. How even docker keeps track that this container is created by this docker-compose.yml file.